# TypeError: check_location() missing 1 required positional argument: 'totalprices' in line 33, in <module>

Tags: python, methods, typeerror, return-type

What I am trying to do is calling in second method (return type from first method - variable which is totalprices). I am not sure if I am calling it right way. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks in advance:

```py
class funda():
    def __init__(self, house_type_list):
        self.house_type_list = house_type_list


    def total_buy_price(self):
        totalprices = 0
        homeprice = self.house_type_list[0]
        maintance = self.house_type_list[1]
        if homeprice < 20000 and maintance <= 150:
            totalprices = homeprice + maintance
            print("home is in budget and home price total is %s in euro " % totalprices)
        else:
            if homeprice >= 20000 and maintance == 100:
                totalprices = homeprice + maintance
                print("not in budget as price is high %s" % totalprices)
                return totalprices

    def check_location(self, totalprices):
        self.total_buy_price()
        parent_totalprice = totalprices
        print("to check if value is coming correct  " +str(parent_totalprice))
        location = self.house_type_list[2]
        if location == 'haarlem' and parent_totalprice <= 20000:
            print("% location is best for rent and  budget " %location)
        else:
            print("Not in budget")

    house_type_list1 = [10000, 100, "Uithoorn"]
    house_type_instance = funda(house_type_list1)
    house_type_instance.total_buy_price()
    house_type_instance.check_location()
    
    print('\n')
    
    house_type_list2 = [22000, 200, "Amsterdam"]
    house_type_instance2 = funda(house_type_list2)
    house_type_instance2.total_buy_price()
    house_type_instance2.check_location()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, the final code is not where it can be

Comment: Could you please let me know what i need to correct exactly. As on pycharm code indentation showing me correctly.

Comment: That exact code cannot work, the final code can't see `funda` to instanciate it